# How to print the filename of the current execution file in python?

Tags: python, file, filenames

I am currently running a script which while execution goes to multiple other python files. My aim is to print the filename of the currently executing file  in python ?

I tried using:

```
print __file__
```

But the following error was thrown:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\qksr\Desktop\work\parsing text\testcase.py", line 32, in <module>
    print __file__
NameError: name '__file__' is not defined
```

So what statement should i code ?

Comment: It works for me. What is your OS?

Comment: @xylon97 mine is windows

Comment: I believe __file__ is undefined when __name__ == '__main__'.

Comment: How is `testcase.py` being executed?

Comment: What does a `print __name__` display if put before the line?

Comment: @martineau its displays: '__main__'

Comment: Try `print os.path.abspath(inspect.getsourcefile(lambda _: None))` following an `import os, inspect` statement.